# Is it safe to execute a new SQLite query while still iterating over the cursor for an earlier query? (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I call SQLiteDatabase.query and get a Cursor. While I'm still iterating over that cursor, is it safe to issue other queries from the same thread?

Comment: I think the answer that you accepted is incorrect.  See the example code in my answer below.

Comment: in execution both cursor will not get execute at same time, when outter cursor is running, inner cursor will be in wait position and vice version @Travis

Comment: I tried ditkin's code and it works: the first query does not lose its place when the second query is executing, which is what I was worried about (or worse, an exception or deadlock). I'm not sure what you are referring to about the wait position. There is only one thread, so obviously there wouldn't be any concurrent or background execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can, from within the same thread, have multiple outstanding queries and independently access each of the cursors.

I added the following code to a test activity and it runs as expected:

```
SQLiteDatabase connection = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase("foo.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
try {
    connection.execSQL("drop table if exists person");
    connection.execSQL("create table person (id integer, name string)");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id", 1);
    cv.put("name", "leo");
    connection.insert("person", null, cv);
    cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id", 2);
    cv.put("name", "yui");
    connection.insert("person", null, cv);

    Cursor rs = connection.query("person", new String[] {"id", "name" }, null, null, null, null, null);

    while(rs.moveToNext())
    {
        System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString(1));
        System.out.println("id = " + rs.getString(0));

        Cursor rs2 = connection.query("person", new String[] {"id", "name" }, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (rs2.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("name = " + rs2.getString(1));
            System.out.println("id = " + rs2.getString(0));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception " + e);
}
```

Comment: in the background, both cursor will get execute one by one only.

Comment: The OP asked if it was safe to execute other queries from the same thread.  It is.

Comment: a query and a cursor at same time from same thread, please read it properly.

Answer (score 3):

**No Two Query gets execute on same table at same time**. It is in-built synchronized method, so at a time it will execute only one query. Your second query will be in wait position until first completes its execution.

Comment: -1 I think this answer is wrong.  You can, from within the same thread, have multiple outstanding queries and independently access each of the cursors.

Comment: BTW sunday stackoverflow par ?

Comment: As ditkin demonstrated with his code, this answer is incorrect. I think Lucifer misunderstood the question. There is only one thread executing in this scenario.

Comment: agree with his code, but as per your question requirement, my answer is correct one. @Travis

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP does not talk about the same table -- just about different queries.  Similarly, the OP isn't talking about a multithreaded situation.